# How can I use cancan to secure all of my controllers in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to add some code into the application_controller so rails automatically secures every controller with cancan, instead of having to add `load_and_authorize_resource` in every controller?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use inheritance:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
 # [etc]
end

class SettingsController < ApplicationController
end

class UsersController < SettingsController
end

class ProductsController < SettingsController
end
```

So you can give access to the SettingsController:

```
can :manage, SettingsController
```

Which will give access to all controllers that inherit from SettingsController.